# как можно сделать верстку блока со стрелками

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу понять как сделать этот блок, есть ли статья или код по таким версткам.
Проблема заключается в правильном расположении стрелок текста и цифр.

Answer (score 1):

Один из методов создать что-то подобное — расположить каждый элемент абсолютно относительно родительского элемента (position: absolute). И для каждого элемента вы разместите эти числа (01, 02, 03...), используя псевдоэлементы (::before, ::after).